# How to get the querystring of an anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I do the following to get the parameter of an anchor tag, but there's probably some better way to do it:

```
$('a').has('.icon-thumbs-up').click(function(e) {
    var local = {};
    e.preventDefault();
    local.href = $(this).attr('href');
    local.X = local.href.indexOf('GuessID=',0) + 8;
    local.Y = local.href.indexOf('&',local.X);
    local.GuessID = local.href.substr(local.X,local.Y-local.X);
```

Q: Is there some sexy jQuery way of getting 123 from href="page.htm?GuessID=123"?

Comment: Someone posted it and then removed it, not sure why.  I'd have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript if you want something more generic.

Comment: As [sexy](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) as it gets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use the overhead of jquery when it's so easy to do naturally with javascript?
Of course this will work and it's making an assumption that the `<a>` has a query string.

```
$('a').has('.icon-thumbs-up').click(function(e) {

     var querystring = $(this).prop('href').split("?")[1]; //GuessID=123&someother=123
     var values = querystring.split("&"); 
     var first =  values[0];  // GuessID=123
     var second = values[1];  // someother=123
});
```